# ASP.NET Hyperlinks asp:HyperLink vs A href

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net when should I use:

```
<asp:HyperLink   
ID="Home"   
runat="server"  
Text="Home"  
NavigateUrl="./Home.aspx">
```

and when shoudl I use

```
<a href="./UnsignedVsSignedTut.aspx">Home</a>
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET server controls give you more abilities (e.g. event handling, more properties). HTML controls on the other hand are much simpler.

Both controls are fine. Usually you can start from HTML control and migrate to asp:HyperLink if need later.

You can also look at these discussions:

- [asp control vs html control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859923/asp-control-vs-html-control)
- [ASP.Net Control vs HTML Control Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876728/asp-net-control-vs-html-control-performance)

Answer (score 1):

1). If you just need a link on a page, use an HTML anchor element (`<a href="...">...</a>`).

2). If you need to dynamically control the link's properties (such as href, text, visibility, etc) use a server-side anchor/link control

Either a server-side "webcontrol" [System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx)

```
<asp:HyperLink id="aExample" runat="server" NavigateUrl="..." .../>
```

or a server-side "htmlcontrol" [System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx)

```
<a id="aExample" runat="server" href="...">...</a>
```

3). Additionally, server-side controls have potential for more sophisticated programming, such as building the anchor element dynamically from a base [System.Web.UI.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `asp:HyperLink` you make it accessible from code behind. Which means like any other ASP.NET controls, you can modify it from code behind. `asp:HyperLink` can also be data bound.

In general case, when you have a static hyperlink I guess you can use both interchangeably.

Comment: You can also use `<a runat="server" id="myAnchor" />` and access that from code-behind.

Comment: @Dai: sure, but can't be data bound.